# Custom sums in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have query that gives back results like this:

```
Client1 Product1 $500
Client1 Product2 $900
Client1 Product3 $400
Client2 Product1 $600
Client2 Product2 $100
```

And I need it like this:

```
Client1 Product1 $500
Client1 Product2 $900
Client1 Product3 $400
Client1 SUM      $1800
Client2 Product1 $600
Client2 Product2 $100
Client2 SUM      $700
```

Is somethig like this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the query to get your initial results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `WITH ROLLUP` expression on your `GROUP BY` statement to achieve the desired results: [Summarizing Data Using ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)